# Magento Tracking Number Omitted

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Magento ver 1.7.0.2

The tracking number is not being written to table 'sales_flat_shipment_track' when the tracking number is added from the following screen:

index.php/admin/sales_order_shipment/new/order_id/###/

'title' and 'carrier_code' are being written fine. We have tried using 'number' and 'tracking_number' as the posted form field's name. I've looked all over but can't seem to find where this logic is handled to determine why this variable is not being written.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field name is `track_number`

Comment: Thanks!! Oversight. Two eyes always help.